# Not able to access image on jsp file

Tags: eclipse, html, spring, css, spring-mvc

[image]

Attaches is the image of my project hierarchy. I am trying to call image from images directory to the jsp file in jsp directory but I am getting blank screen.

So far I have tried :

/WEB-INF/images/'<'imageFileName'>'

/images/'<'imageFileName'>'

/'<'imageFileName'>'

src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/images/'<'imageFileName'>'

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access any resources that are under `WEB-INF` folder, it serves just that purpose, to hold the resources that are not directly visible for the public but available to the classloader (servlets) of your web app.

You should make a mapping by the means of `mvc:resources` element, you should checkout the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-static-resources)

for your particular case a mapping like

`<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/WEB-INF/images"/>`

should work out, and you'll be able to browse your images via request such as

`/images/'<'imageFileName'>'`

Answer (score 0):

You can place your images and jsp folder under the web-app folder rather than WEB-INF folder. Then you can access the images using:

```
/images/'<'imageFileName'>'
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSPs cannot access files inside WEB-INF folder directly, since it's not publicly available.  But you can access it indirectly through a Servlet which will return the Image's stream object.

The sample code to access files in WEB-INF folder is in the below link.  Have a look.

http://simple.souther.us/ar01s10.html

Comment: It is possible to access it through CSS, If yes then how? Please explain.

Comment: Not its not possible to access it through CSS.  Its better if you re-arrange your package structure by moving the JSP and Images folder under your webapp folder.

Comment: Will not this be a security concern, if I place the jsp, images, css & js folders outsider WEB-INF directory ?